# What role does the number "77" play?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

At the beginning of the game, you receive a telegram which tells you to avoid the number 77.  Further down the line, during the chapter, you enter a raffle in which the number you pick is 77, and ends up leading to your first "firefight".

I'm curious as to whether or not the number 77 plays a role anywhere else?

Side question: Who sent the telegram?

Comment: I so much love such lore questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The number 77 is not important besides the fact that Booker picks it. The telegram is sent by one of the Lutece siblings.

Ending game *SPOILERS*:

> That number is practically picked by Booker in all dimensions (a "constant") and that is why Robert Lutece, by using that telegram, attempts to prevent it from happening as a "scientific" bet against Rosalind Lutece.
>  Both Robert and Rosalind are having a "bet" on whether they can, or not, significantly change the timeline while having the same initial variables and constants. Robert believes that they can (and is losing the bet), Rosalind does not.

Comment: Wow.  Insightful.  Good answer!

Comment: Booker's Pinkerton badge (in his office and in the loading screens) also features the number 727 and he was in the 7th cavalry regiment.